# What is the difference between "festo" and "ferio"?

Tags: word-choice

Both *festo* and *ferio* seem to generally translate to English as "holiday", but are they actually interchangeable, or is there a difference that the English translation doesn't preserve?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

They're different. While "holiday" is *a* valid translation for both, the two have different meanings (which are preserved in English). The PIV has the following definitions for the two words:

> **festo**. Publikaj aŭ privataj ceremonioj k plezuroj por festi iun okazaĵon: *festo de Kristnasko, de Budhonasko, de Pasko, de Pentekosto, de la Unua de Majo, de la 14a de Julio; edziĝa festo; intima festo; ĝojan feston! (deziresprimo); kies gasto mi estas, ties feston mi festas; ofta festo, malplena kesto; post la fasto venas festo; enmeti specialan feston por mia honoro; niaj kongresoj fariĝos konstanta festo de la homa frateco; profani nian feston per semado de malpaco.*
>
> **ferio**. Libera tago, dum kiu oni rajtas ne labori: *havi ferion okaze de la vizito de regnestro; kiam komenciĝos viaj ferioj?; la someraj, vintraj, lernejaj ferioj; banka ferio (en kiu la bankoj estas leĝe fermitaj).*

Per these definitions, a *festo* is a celebration of some occasion, while a *ferio* is a day on which one's entitled to not work. Obviously there's some overlap; *Kristnasko* (or Christmas) is part of the definition of *festo*, but for many people it's also a *ferio*.